# How to search a field having a colon(:) value in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, wildcard, querydsl, mac-address

i have a field `"macaddress": "ff:ff:00:57:29:05"`

How can i escape colon(:) from treating it as regex wildcard. Tried escaping string with slash(\) but query is failing

```
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "macaddress": "57:"
    }
 }
}
```

i want to search something like 57:25*, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wildcard use match_phase instead.
[wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) are * which matches any character sequence (including the empty one), and ?, which matches any single character.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase":{
            "macaddress":"57:29"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using `match_phrase` or `prefix`, etc could be an alternative. But wanted to know how we can escape such special chars while doing a wildcard search

Comment: @Steve okay.. i went through no. Of threads.. each one says wildcard can't escape colon.. but i will look for it..